# Bind DataGridComboBoxColumn to entity

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two simple entities: Country and Continent

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Continent Continent { get; set; }

}

public class Continent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FIFA_Abbrevation { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display in DataGrid a list of countries with combobox where we can change continent. How can i bind it?

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="continentCollection" Source="{Binding continentCollection}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="countryCollection" Source="{Binding countryCollection}" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"  Name="dgv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource countryCollection}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="4*" Header="Nazwa" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="1*" Header="Kontynent" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource continentCollection}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Continent}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.Country> countryCollection { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Model.Continent> continentCollection { get; set; }
```

I'm displaying only names of countries and name of continents in combobox, but continents are not set.
[Image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/l20gpZpoRr2XvOlWmWtlbQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedItemBinding` property:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="1*" Header="Kontynent" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource continentCollection}}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Continent}" />
```